# Intuition behind unitary equivalence

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, intuition, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

We say that two elements $a,b$ in some $C^*$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ are unitarily equivalent if there exists a unitary $u$ in the unitarization of $\mathcal{A}$ such that $a = ubu^*$. Is it possible to provide some simple intuition regarding how similar $a$ and $b$ are, when this condition holds? And similarly, can one obtain some intuition when $a$ and $b$ are approximately unitarily equivalent?

Comment: There is nothing unclear about this question.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I disagree.  If the answer isn't that $a$ and $b$ differ by exactly one conjugation by a unitary operator, then I don't understand what it is that the original questioner is asking.  Of course, if that is the answer, then I'm not sure what the point of the question is...

Comment: @XanderHenderson: really? Your claim is that the only *intuition* about a definition is to repeat the definition? The question is very concrete and very clear. If it weren't on hold, an answer could delve on how two normal matrices are unitarily equivalent if and only if they have the same list of eigenvalues, counting multiplicities. Or it could also mention [Specht's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specht%27s_theorem) and other results and characterizations. And then there's still the difference with approximate unitary equivalence.

Comment: There is one, and only one, way to acquire intuition: exercise. It can't be explained (by definition, if there were a definition of "intuition"), and I've never seen anybody getting it by asking bad questions.

Comment: @ProfessorVector: then, of course, you teach Riemann integration, geometry, and graphs without drawing pictures, right?

Comment: @Martin Argerami There are infinitely many things unrelated to what I wrote, why did you choose that? I don't teach maths at all (at least, not in the last 20 years). Of course I would use pictures, where they help. I have to admit that I can't immediately come up with a nice picture helping to understand unitary equivalence, though. Whatever: intuition is not a mathematical notion, so any question concerning that can't ever be considered "clear".

Comment: But you said that intuition can't be explained. Which precisely what anyone does when you draw pictures to explain a concept. There are lots and lots of things one can say about the intuition behind unitary equivalence. I already mentioned a couple above, that would have been in my answer had this question not been closed in a rush. And I could mention more, like for example the fact that unitary equivalence corresponds to a change of orthonormal basis. And, by the way, searching for "intuition" in MSE gives 25431 hits. You have a lot of closing votes to give there.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Again, "intuition" is not a definable mathematical term.  What is intuitive for me (hey, it is completely obvious that the Cantor set displays oscillatory geometry and should possess a periodic set of complex dimensions on the line $s = \log_3(2) + \tau i$ for $\tau\in\mathbb{R}$, derp derp derp) is entirely unintuitive and nonobvious to someone who doesn't even know what is meant by "oscillatory geometry" or a "complex dimension."  The way to build intuition is to work with the definitions in order to gain familiarity with the basic definitions and ideas.

Comment: It sounds like you claim that in math there is no role for explanations.